# Tomcat throws an exception when finishing a Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, tomcat9

Sometimes when Tomcat has been running for a while and I terminate the embeded Tomcat (Ctrl+c) the application throws the following exception:

`2019-10-17 10:23:10.704  INFO 20020 --- [       Thread-3] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/SpringBeanContainer$SpringContainedBean
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/catalina/Lifecycle$SingleUse
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:269)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.stop(Tomcat.java:466)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.stopTomcat(TomcatWebServer.java:254)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.stop(TomcatWebServer.java:309)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.stopAndReleaseWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:305)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onClose(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:171)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1032)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$1.run(AbstractApplicationContext.java:945)`

It seems that the exception is thrown when Tomcat has been running for a long time and my application has not been used.

I checked my application jar file and `spring-orm-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar` is embeded and the class `org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/SpringBeanContainer` is there.

Any idea is apreciated.

Comment: Are you getting this frequently or sometimes?

Comment: Sometimes, as I said, mainly when I leave Tomcat running and the application is not used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to shutdown the application before replacing or renaming the jar.

@see [Graceful shutdown fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65090165/graceful-shutdown-fails)