# Graceful shutdown fails

Tags: spring-boot, shutdown

I have a spring boot 2.3+ application with server.shutdown=graceful which, when getting shut down throws:

```
 2020-11-30 11:07:35.485  WARN 3038 --- [SpringContextShutdownHook] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Failed to stop bean 'webServerGracefulShutdown'
 
 java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/web/server/GracefulShutdownResult
     at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.WebServerGracefulShutdownLifecycle.stop(WebServerGracefulShutdownLifecycle.java:51)
     at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStop(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:238)
     at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$300(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53)
     at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.stop(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:377)
     at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.stopBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:210)
     at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onClose(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:128)
     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1022)
     at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.doClose(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:170)
     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$1.run(AbstractApplicationContext.java:949)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/web/server/GracefulShutdownResult
     ... 9 common frames omitted
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.web.server.GracefulShutdownResult
     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
     at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
     ... 9 common frames omitted
 
 2020-11-30 11:08:05.486  INFO 3038 --- [SpringContextShutdownHook] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Failed to shut down 1 bean with phase value 2147483647 within timeout of 30000ms: [webServerGracefulShutdown]
 2020-11-30 11:08:35.514  INFO 3038 --- [SpringContextShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
 2020-11-30 11:08:35.519  INFO 3038 --- [SpringContextShutdownHook] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
 2020-11-30 11:08:35.520  INFO 3038 --- [SpringContextShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
 2020-11-30 11:08:35.528  INFO 3038 --- [SpringContextShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
 2020-11-30 11:08:35.530  INFO 3038 --- [SpringContextShutdownHook] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Shutting down ExecutorService
```

In the end the application is shutdown, however not gracefully, and since the shutdown is being called from a deployment script, the script fails, due to the exit code != 0 of the app's shutdown call.

What could be the cause of this? I think I don't have long running tasks, which can cause this, but how can I check it?

Comment: Did you replaced the jar or renamed the jar before calling shutdown api ?

Comment: Well, the `server.shutdown=graceful` setting is in `application.properties` getting bundled into the jar. If this setting is on, then the jar is replaced.

Comment: Try calling the shutdown before jar replacement and see what happens.

Comment: @Shawrup, thanks, that was the problem. Fixed now. Do you care to convert it to an answer?

Comment: Sure, I will be writing an asnwer for this question.

Comment: Above issue got reproduced while replacing the jar before killing existing

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This problem might happen if you replace or rename the jar while the jar is still running. Java does not take the whole jar in memory at startup and uses reference for classes in the Jar when it needs to load some classes. But renaming the jar or replacing the jar can mess up the class references inside the Jar. So java will not find the class you want to load at runtime and you will be presented with this `ClassNotFoundException`.

`Possible workaround:` Try to shutdown the application before replacing or renaming the jar.

Answer (score 0):

We are experiencing the same issue in our git lab pipeline, I have changed the pipeline to stop the existing app first and then replace the new jar file. Hopefully, this would solve the issue.